# Detecting syncing event for iOS

Tags: iphone

Is there any way if my iphone app can detect if the user is trying to sync the iphone device when the app runs? My app crashes a lot when this syncing occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App Delegate receives a `applicationWillResignActive:` call, nothing more. You can't be sure if its because of syncing or because your user got a call.

About the crashes, make sure that you respond to memory warnings by freeing up as much memory as possible for the system, this should solve the problem in 99% of the cases.

Comment: actually I have a problem with this solution. This is because my app is supposed to play music at the background or when screen is locked. using applicationwillresign will pause the app in both cases when the screen is locked and when there is a phone call or sync event